# Naturality of Riesz' Representation

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

What does it mean precisely in the context of category theory when somebody says that Riesz' representation is **canonic** resp. every Hilbert space is **naturally** antiisomorphic to its dual?

Comment: It is a natural antiequivalence in the category of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Sorry, it is not an anti equivalence, but for subspaces of a given Hilbert space I think you got a natural equivalence between the functors transposition and hermitian adjoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very interesting issue. In fact, this isomorphism is *not* as "natural" as one might have thought. As an exercise, one should see that, given a map of Hilbert spaces $V\to W$ it is rarely the case that the square of maps involving $W^*\to V^*$ and the "Riesz-Fisher" dualities ... commutes. This is fairly crazy, yes, given the standard curriculum.

A similar deceptive fake-issue arises while thinking about Sobolev spaces.

Comment: Which square do you mean? We have $R_V\circ T^\ast = {}^tT\circ R_W$, where $R_X$ denotes the Riesz map $X\to X^\ast$, $T^\ast$ is the Hilbert-adjoint, and ${}^tT$ the dual/transpose/Banach-adjoint of $T$, so that one commutes.

Comment: @DanielFischer, what about the inclusion $T:H^1\to H^o=L^2$, (ignoring complex conjugation...) adjoint-identification of $H^o$ with itself, so $T^*:H^o\to H^{-1}$ is the adjoint. Following three sides of the square, $H^1\to H^o \to H^{-1}$. But this composite is certainly not an isomorphism.

Comment: Ah, you mean ${}^tT\circ R_W \circ T \neq R_V$ (in general). Is that a natural expectation, though, from the correspondence $T^\ast \leftrightarrow {}^tT$?

Comment: @DanielFischer, yes, since transpose reverses direction of arrows, the "natural" candidate for "commuting" has to be that going around 3 sides of a square is equal to going around the 1 other.